# Accessing more complex JSON with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, getjson

I am trying to access this data from a JSON file I have created:

```
{
  "game":"one",
  "schedule":[
    {
      "day":"mon",
      "start":"00:00:00",
      "end":"05:30:00"
    },
    {
      "day":"tue",
      "start":"00:00:00",
      "end":"05:30:00"
    }
  ],
  "game":"two",
  "schedule":[
    {
      "day":"mon",
      "start":"00:00:00",
      "end":"05:30:00"
    },
    {
      "day":"wed",
      "start":"00:00:00",
      "end":"05:30:00"
    }
  ],
  "game":"three",
  "schedule":[
    {
      "day":"fri",
      "start":"00:00:00",
      "end":"05:30:00"
    },
    {
      "day":"thu",
      "start":"00:00:00",
      "end":"05:30:00"
    }
  ]
}
```

This is how I am trying to access it:

```
  $.getJSON(json_location, function(data) {
    $.each(data.schedule, function() {
      console.log(this.day + " " + this.start + " " + this.end);
    });
  });
```

However this only returns the values within game three - so: fri 00:00:00 05:30:00, thu 00:00:00 05:30:00. Ideally I want to be able to iterate through game one, then two, then three. However regardless of how much I try to adapt my code I cannot allow $.getJSON to access the data.

I am also aware that this format is valid to use with javascript, however not valid according to RFC 4627 (JSON specification) - so any suggestions on how to improve the layout of the JSON would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: i suggest that you name the schedule according to which game they are under example instead of   `"schedule":[
    {
      "day":"fri",
      "start":"00:00:00",
      "end":"05:30:00"
    },
    {
      "day":"thu",
      "start":"00:00:00",
      "end":"05:30:00"
    }
  ]` have   `"game 1":[
    {
      "day":"fri",
      "start":"00:00:00",
      "end":"05:30:00"
    },
    {
      "day":"thu",
      "start":"00:00:00",
      "end":"05:30:00"
    }
  ]`

Comment: The issue is with the format of your JSON. You have repeated properties at the same level. This means the previous will be over-written, so only the final one will be accessible.

Comment: The way you created your JSON data is simply wrong. You must group those properties into objects

Comment: you need to have something like {0:{game: "one", schedule {[<-dt->], [<-dt->]}}, 1:{game: "two", schedule {[<-dt->], [<-dt->]}}, 2: {game: "three", schedule {[<-dt->], [<-dt->]}} }, then iterate through each of the game and for each game loop through schedule and do your thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, this JSON is wrong since there are multiple values for the same keys game and schedule

try something like this (simplest change)

```
{
  "one":[
    {
      "day":"mon",
      "start":"00:00:00",
      "end":"05:30:00"
    },
    {
      "day":"tue",
      "start":"00:00:00",
      "end":"05:30:00"
    }
  ],
  "two":[
    {
      "day":"mon",
      "start":"00:00:00",
      "end":"05:30:00"
    },
    {
      "day":"wed",
      "start":"00:00:00",
      "end":"05:30:00"
    }
  ],
  "three":[
    {
      "day":"fri",
      "start":"00:00:00",
      "end":"05:30:00"
    },
    {
      "day":"thu",
      "start":"00:00:00",
      "end":"05:30:00"
    }
  ]
}
```

then iterate it like

```
for ( var gameId in data )
{
   var scheduleArray = data[ gameId ];
//iterate this array
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON data is wrong. You have 3 schedule items instead of 3 objects containing a schedule

```
[ // array of games
{ // first game and schedule
"game":"one",
"schedule":[
  {
  "day":"mon",
  "start":"00:00:00",
  "end":"05:30:00"
  },
  {
  "day":"tue",
  "start":"00:00:00",
  "end":"05:30:00"
  }
  ]
},
{ // second game and schedule
"game": "two",
"schedule": [
    ..
]
},
etc
]
```

Comment: No offense meant, but you should rather post it as comment.. because this ain't gonna answer OP's question..

Comment: No offense taken but I tend to post quick answers, then pad them out with details. Wait till you pounce :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've defined `"game"` and `"schedule"` three times each on the top level of the object. Just modify your JSON to make sense: perhaps you should have an array of game objects with a `"number"` and a `"schedule"` field for each one.

Answer (score 0):

past your json code into this site and formate it proper.
http://json.parser.online.fr/